# ThreeJS Load GLTF Model From File Input

Tags: three.js

I want to be able to allow users to select their own gltf model for display, which means I need an input tag

```
<input type="file" @change="onFileChange" multiple>
```

And then I do it like this:

```
function onFileChange(e: any) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const arrayBuffer = reader.result as ArrayBuffer;
      // 使用 Three.js 的 GLTFLoader 加载模型
      const loader = new GLTFLoader();
      loader.parse(arrayBuffer, '', (gltf) => {
        // 将模型添加到场景中
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
      });
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
}
```

But this only loads the glb file, and when I select the gltf file together with its texture (.bin) and texture (.png), the browser reports an error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61fgi.png)
How can I display the model directly from the selected file in the input tag?